# How to use a final variable in other activities?

Tags: java, android

I tried to add a photo of my code but it was not uploading since it was above 2MB.

Instead of changing the size I decided to choose another picture to complete the formality. However, my question is simple, it doesn't need any additional code to be understood.

[image: Image of cup. Desc: My code never has bugs It just develops random unexpected features.]

Comment: Your question body doesn't seem to match your question title.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see these few links about asking good questions; [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also to show code you should not use an image, you should indent copy and paste you code into your question, formatting each line with four spaces at the start. This highlights your code and makes it easier for others to read

Comment: @ThePythonInventor Did my answer answer your question or were you struggling with something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a public static final variable. For example

```
public static final int FINAL_INT = 3;
```

---

**Usage**

You would then call this in your other activity.

```
MyActivity.FINAL_INT
```